# Fastest way to update (populate) 1,000,000 records into a database using .NET

Tags: c#, .net, sql, nosql, localdb

I am using this code to insert 1 million records into an empty table in the database.  Ok so without much code I will start from the point I have already interacted with data, and read the schema into a `DataTable`:

So:

```
DataTable returnedDtViaLocalDbV11 = DtSqlLocalDb.GetDtViaConName(strConnName, queryStr, strReturnedDtName);
```

And now that we have `returnedDtViaLocalDbV11` lets create a new `DataTable` to be a clone of the source database table:

```
DataTable NewDtForBlkInsert = returnedDtViaLocalDbV11.Clone();

Stopwatch SwSqlMdfLocalDb11 = Stopwatch.StartNew();
NewDtForBlkInsert.BeginLoadData();

for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
{
   NewDtForBlkInsert.LoadDataRow(new object[] { null, "NewShipperCompanyName"+i.ToString(), "NewShipperPhone" }, false);
}
NewDtForBlkInsert.EndLoadData();

DBRCL_SET.UpdateDBWithNewDtUsingSQLBulkCopy(NewDtForBlkInsert, tblClients._TblName, strConnName);

SwSqlMdfLocalDb11.Stop();

var ResSqlMdfLocalDbv11_0 = SwSqlMdfLocalDb11.ElapsedMilliseconds;
```

This code is populating 1 million records to an embedded SQL database (localDb) in **5200ms**. The rest of the code is just implementing the bulkCopy but I will post it anyway.

```
 public string UpdateDBWithNewDtUsingSQLBulkCopy(DataTable TheLocalDtToPush, string TheOnlineSQLTableName, string WebConfigConName)
 {
    //Open a connection to the database. 
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[WebConfigConName].ConnectionString))
    {
       connection.Open();

       // Perform an initial count on the destination table.
       SqlCommand commandRowCount = new SqlCommand("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "+TheOnlineSQLTableName +";", connection);
       long countStart = System.Convert.ToInt32(commandRowCount.ExecuteScalar());

       var nl = "\r\n";
       string retStrReport = "";
       retStrReport = string.Concat(string.Format("Starting row count = {0}", countStart), nl);
       retStrReport += string.Concat("==================================================", nl);
       // Create a table with some rows. 
       //DataTable newCustomers = TheLocalDtToPush;

       // Create the SqlBulkCopy object.  
       // Note that the column positions in the source DataTable  
       // match the column positions in the destination table so  
       // there is no need to map columns.  
       using (SqlBulkCopy bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(connection))
       {
          bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = TheOnlineSQLTableName;

          try
          {
             // Write from the source to the destination.
             for (int colIndex = 0; colIndex < TheLocalDtToPush.Columns.Count; colIndex++)
             {
                bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add(colIndex, colIndex);
             }
             bulkCopy.WriteToServer(TheLocalDtToPush);
          }

          catch (Exception ex)
          {
             Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
          }
       }

       // Perform a final count on the destination  
       // table to see how many rows were added. 
       long countEnd = System.Convert.ToInt32(
       commandRowCount.ExecuteScalar());

       retStrReport += string.Concat("Ending row count = ", countEnd, nl);
       retStrReport += string.Concat("==================================================", nl);
       retStrReport += string.Concat((countEnd - countStart)," rows were added.", nl);
       retStrReport += string.Concat("New Customers Was updated successfully", nl, "END OF PROCESS !");
       //Console.ReadLine();
       return retStrReport;
   }
}
```

Trying it via a connection to SQL server was around 7000ms(at best) & ~7700ms average. Also via a random kv nosql database took around 40 sec (really I did not even keep records of it as it passed over the x2 of sql variants). So... is there a faster way than what I was testing in my code?

**Edit**

i am using win7 x64 8gb ram and most important i should think (as i5 3ghz) is not so great by now
the x3 500Gb Wd on Raid-0 does the job even better 
but i am just saying if you will check on your pc 
though just compare it to any other method in your configuration

Comment: "NoSQL" is not a specific database engine or storage mechanism. What engine?

Comment: Skip the overhead of the DataTable.  If must use DataTable then why not use the existing feature http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh485668.aspx?

Comment: Never mind, I see you are using that method.  Still I would try not using DataTable at all.

Comment: @Blam some automation ... not declaring types of data in each column and such, so you suggest using dictionaries or hashtables ?
i mean i am realy not that great inventor, just testing all i see what could u save more, if its around 20% or more maybe it will be good to test too

Comment: You think the only way to type data is via DataTable?

Comment: @Blam started with `dictionary<T, T>` and that class wich you probably know that could interact with any databse but i liked the data table (autmatic gears) though i will be more than happy to see what you would do to improve pref ..

Comment: What part of DataTable has overhead is not clear?  Just look at the number number of methods and properties supported.

Comment: ok so make `List<Dictionary<string, object>> table;` ... and check again ? you think it is less resources ,  and then to send it to the `bulk.Copy(what here ? )` i have no clue as to how to pass other than dt

Comment: 7 seconds for a million records, not really seeing the problem.

Comment: I was thinking the same thing.  I was just testing this same option for some ETL work I have to do - on my I7, 16GB of Ram and SSD I was able to get 10,000,000 records to insert in about 65 seconds so these numbers seem fairly accurate.

Comment: Instead of scalarReader - Use a forward only data reader - SqlDataReader myReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried SSIS? I have never written an SSIS package with a loacldb connection, but this is the sort of activity SSIS should be well suited.

If your data source is a SQL Server, another idea would be setting up a linked server. Not sure if this would work with localdb. If you can set up a linked server, you could bypass the C# all together and load your data with an INSERT .. SELECT ... FROM ... SQL statement.

Comment: could you be more specific as to how would you suggest implementing ssis with my code, is it a server code, is it like stroed procidure or how is it working so you came to the idea of it helping to reduce task done by c#

Comment: If I am reading your code correctly, you're populating data from a source database, then loading into the destination. I'm thinking with SSIS you could skip the DataTable and pump data directly to the destination. SSIS (SQL Server Integration Services) is a data integration platform that comes with SQL Server.

Comment: sure, thanks Mike.. i will be 'researching' the SSIS approach, i had a look on it in a glance though it needs some more time spent (more than 2 minutes (: ) to understand consept and uscase etc', as i am not informed on its existence till now i am sure i at least could understand what it is about

Comment: There's a visual designer for SSIS built into Visual Studio. You'll need to do a little research, but for moving data in bulk there's nothing that comes close in terms of performance.

Answer (score 1):

you can use `Dapper.NET`.
Dapper is a micro-ORM, executes a query and map the results to a strongly typed List.
Object-relational mapping (ORM, O/RM, and O/R mapping) in computer software is a programming technique for converting data between incompatible type systems in object-oriented programming languages. This creates, in effect, a “virtual object database” that can be used from within the programming language

For more info:

check out https://code.google.com/p/dapper-dot-net/

GitHub Repository:   https://github.com/SamSaffron/dapper-dot-net
Hope It helps..

Answer (score 1):

Remove looping... In SQL, try to make a table with 1 million rows... and left join it use this for insert/select data

Answer (score 0):

Try sending it without storing it in a datatable.

See the example at the end of this post, that allows you to do it with an enumerator http://www.developerfusion.com/article/122498/using-sqlbulkcopy-for-high-performance-inserts/

Comment: thanks i will look in to this, it sure looks interesting option i will give it a test to check how much time-save it gains over datatable , it also uses datareader vs dataset... ill get to it soon i hope (:

Answer (score 0):

If you are just creating nonsense data, create a stored procedure and just call that through .net

If you are passing real data, again passing it to a stored proc would be quicker but you would be best off dropping the table and recreating it with the data.

If you insert one row at a time, it will take longer than inserting it all at once. It will take even longer if you have indexes to write.

Answer (score 0):

Create a single XML file for all rows you want to save into data base. Pass this XML to SQL stored procedure and save all record in one call only.
But your stored procedure must be written so that it can read all read then insert into table.

Comment: I don`t think this is going to be faster. Moreover working with xml and files is much slower than just simply work with the database.

Answer (score 0):

If this is a new project I recommend you to use [Entity Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/bb399567.aspx). In this case you can create a List<> with an object with all the data you need and then simply add it entirely to the corresponding table. 
This way you are quickly geting the needed data and then sending it to the database at once.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Mike on SSIS but it my not suit your environment, however for ETL processes that involve cross server calls and general data flow processes it is a great built in tool and highly integrated.

With 1 million rows you will likely have to do a bulk insert.  Depending on the row size you would not really be able to use a stored procedure unless you did this in batches.  A datatable will fill memory pretty quick, again depending on the row size.  You could make a stored procedure and have that take a table type and call that every X number of rows but why would we do this when you already have a better, more scalable solution.  That million rows could be 50 million next year.

I have used SSIS a bit and if that is an organizational fit I would suggest looking at it, but it wouldn't be a one time answer, wouldn't be worth the dependencies.